# Git commit in my case

Tags: git, github

I am on branch "`feature`". After I did all the changes, I decide to commit my work on this branch.

I first checked all the changes I have made by execute command:

```
git status
```

The above git command printed out the following result:

```
On branch feature
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   MyApp/src/Main.java
#   modified:   MyApp/src/Model.java

# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   MyApp/src/other/file1
#   MyApp/src/other/file2
```

As you see above, there are two **untracked** files `file1` and `file2`. I don't want to have them in my git repository at all. But for some reason I forgot these two files & directly committed my changes by:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Some changes"
```

At this point, all the changes including `file1` & `file2` are commited. Now, how can I rescue myself to **exclude** `file1` & `file2` but still keep other modified changes be committed?

(Please don't suggest me to delete `file1` & `file2` from disk, I need them on my local disk)

Comment: see undo a commti and redo in https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html see

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you committed and realized you didn't want to add those files, you can fix like this:

```
git reset HEAD^ --soft
git reset MyApp/src/other/file1 MyApp/src/other/file2
git commit -m "Some changes"
```

`git reset HEAD^ --soft` will undo the last commit: your working directory will be restored to the state it was before the commit. Thanks to the `--soft` flag, the staging area will be preserved as it was, so you can unstage the two files using `git reset` and commit again.

If you don't want to add those files to version control, then you probably want to ignore them, by adding them to the `.gitignore` file of your project:

```
echo MyApp/src/other/file1 >> .gitignore
echo MyApp/src/other/file2 >> .gitignore
```

PS: thank you [@hekdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060656/dekdev) for the `--soft` tip.

Comment: The only difference between `--soft` and `--mixed` (the default) is that soft keeps the files staged. Since the problem is that those files were staged when they should not have been, using `--soft` would then require another `git reset` to upstage those files.

Comment: I don't get what does "git reset  .../file2" mean? Does this command revert back file2 to be untracked ?

Comment: `git reset file1` removes changes of file1 from the staging area. The file content doesn't change in your working directory. This is all about staging. When something is not staged, it will not be committed when you do `git commit`.

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
git rm --chached path_to_file
```

To tell git to stop tracking `file1` and `file2`. They'll appear as deleted but they will still exist in the directory. Then you'd add the deletions via `git add`.

You can optionally add the files to your `.gitignore`, so git won't track them in the future.
Then you'd amend your last commit with the changes:

```
git commit --amend
```

Hope it helps you!